# Obtener mayor temperatura y a la hora que fue

Tags: array, vb.net

Tengo una pequeña subrutina donde tengo dos arrays (uno de temperaturas y otro de horas).
Debo sacar la mayor temperatura y a la hora que fue. Pero al momento de cargar los datos, si ingreso apenas dos datos, la subrutina funciona correctamente, de lo contrario, si ingreso mas datos, comienza a imprimir muchas veces.

Aquí el código.

```
**Sub InformeTemperaturasMaximas(ByRef temperaturasArray() As Double, ByRef horasArray() As Byte)
        Dim i As Integer

        Dim maxTemp As Byte = 0

        ''PARA SACAR LA TEMPERATURA MAXIMA

        For i = 1 To UBound(temperaturasArray)

            For j = 1 To UBound(horasArray)

                If temperaturasArray(i) > temperaturasArray(maxTemp) Then

                    maxTemp = i

                End If

                Console.WriteLine("La temperatura maxima es de: " & temperaturasArray(maxTemp) & " " & "C°" & " " & "a las" & " " & horasArray(j) & "hs.")

            Next

        Next


    End Sub**
```

Comment: Tienes la instrucción para imprimir dentro del for, por lo tanto se imprimirá tantas veces como datos haya en el array.

Comment: lo he sacado del for pero ya no funciona

Comment: Solo necesita un bucle para recorrer la arregla de temperaturas.  Cuando lo encuentre, guardar la indice y usarla para mostrar la hora.

Comment: La variable j la declaras al inicio del for por lo que está fuera del alcance o scope. ¿Has probado a declararla fuera del for como haces con la variable i? Dim j as integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver, solo pude hacer el ejercicio con VBA en excel

```
Sub InformeTemperaturasMaximas()

    'creo dos array simulados, uno de temperaturas y otro de horas
    Dim temperaturasArray(8) As Integer
        temperaturasArray(0) = 5
        temperaturasArray(1) = 12
        temperaturasArray(2) = 23
        temperaturasArray(3) = 6
        temperaturasArray(4) = 24
        temperaturasArray(5) = 18
        temperaturasArray(6) = 15
        temperaturasArray(7) = 20

    Dim horasArray(8) As Integer
        horasArray(0) = 14
        horasArray(1) = 15
        horasArray(2) = 16
        horasArray(3) = 17
        horasArray(4) = 18
        horasArray(5) = 19
        horasArray(6) = 20
        horasArray(7) = 21

        'creamos la variable del bucle
        Dim i As Integer

        'creamos una variable para la temperatura máxima a cero
        Dim maxTemp As Integer
        maxTemp = 0
        'creamos una variable para la hora a cero
        Dim horTemp As Integer
        horTemp = 0

        ''PARA SACAR LA TEMPERATURA MAXIMA

        For i = 0 To UBound(temperaturasArray)

            'evaluamos que la temperatura del array sea mayor que la variable de la temperatura máxima
            If temperaturasArray(i) > maxTemp Then

                'si la temperatura es mayor, almacenamos esa temperatura en la variable
                maxTemp = temperaturasArray(i)
                'almacenamos la posición horaria que corresponde con la temperatura
                horTemp = horasArray(i)

            End If          
        Next

        'sacamos un aviso por pantalla con el texto de la temperatura y la hora        
        MsgBox ("La temperatura maxima es de: " & maxTemp & " " & "C°" & " " & "a las" & " " & horTemp & "hs.")

End Sub
```